# Facebook plugin in phonegap has some alerts with cordova 1.8.0

Tags: facebook, cordova

It was working fine with Cordova 1.6.1,but trying with cardova 1.8.0 ,
I get these alerts:
1. Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on login!
2. Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on auth.status!
What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two phones one with android 2.2.1 and the other with android 2.3.3 and I get the error on the 2.2.1 but not on the 2.3.3 not sure why but maybe you should try installing on another phone. I'm wondering if its timing out as this old HTC is slow.